# Transition not apply on "img" tag in hover in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to move `img` to top 4px when parent tag `a` is hovered. So I have something like this :

```
<a href="">
    <img src="GitHub.png" alt="GitHub" />
</a>
```

And my CSS :

```
a:hover > img {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 4px;
}
```

When I apply `transition` to `a` or `img`, it doesn't move smoothly.
What's my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` instead of `bottom`.

```css
a:hover > img {
  position: relative;
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

img {
  transition: transform 1s;
 }
```

```html
<a href="">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/50" alt="GitHub" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with keyframes:

```css
.first:hover > img {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes move {
  from {top: 0;}
  to {top: 4px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="body" style="position: relative;">


<a class="first" href="">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100"/>
</a>


</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I prefer to use `transition` alone.

Answer (score 0):

For the transition effect to work, You should apply the transition on the selector and declare what the property you want to transitions original state in that selector. The final state of the transitioned property should be declared in the pseudo class.

The reason you were having issues is because you were declaring the tags position: relative only when hovered and never stated what the default state of the tag should be.
I recommend you check out this [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/learn-css/lessons/animation-transitions) lesson on transitions to get a better understanding. For a practical example here is a w3schools [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_anim_top) that shows off the effect.

Finally for your code here is an example of what will work!

```
a > img {
position: relative;
top: 0;
transition: top 1s;
}

a:hover > img {
top: 4px;
}
```